# Use timespan to add intervals over 24 hours

Tags: c#, timespan

I've an app designed to calculate how many hours employees work. I have to show total for every week. To do it, I loop on every day, and every day I use Add() method. At the end I write hours and minutes on a label.

```
foreach (DataRow day in days.Rows)
{
    TimeSpan tsToAdd = new TimeSpan((int)day["hours"], (int)day["minutues"],0);
    ts = ts.Add(tsToAdd);
}
label.text= ts.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString("00");
```

But, when ts.hours exceeds 24, it restart from 0. For example, 25 hours and 30 minutes became 1 hour and 30 minutes.
I try to use TotalHour and TotalMinutes, but it's not what I want.

How to show, for example, "30:20"?

Thx

Comment: What is wrong with `TotalHours`? `((int)ts.TotalHours).ToString("00")`

Comment: If I have 4 days with a total of 36 hours, total hours is correct but total miutes show minutes contained in 36 hours, so the result is 36:2160

Comment: Don't use both `TotalHours` *and* `TotalMinutes`, use `TotalHours` *with* `Minutes` (per my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeSpan` tries to keep all its values within normal conventions for clock times - so `Hours` should always be in the range 0-23, `Minutes` is always 0-59 etc. If you create a `TimeSpan` with 25 hours, it will realise that this is one day and one hour, so `Hours` will show as `1`, while `Days` will be `1` also.

You can get the total number of hours represented by the `TimeSpan` using the `TotalHours` property. This is a `float`, and includes the minutes, seconds etc. in the `TimeSpan` as well, so a span of 1 day, 1 hour and 1 minute has a `TotalHours` value of `25.01666667`.

So to show the hours like you want, you'll need to discard that fractional component when formatting `TotalHours` for display. `Math.Floor` seems like a good choice for this, but it won't work for negative timespans so the correct choice is `Math.Truncate`.

```
Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours).ToString("00") + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString("00")
```

Although actually when using `ToString` with such a format string, the `Math.Truncate` call isn't necessary as it has the same effect, so provided you want a string you can leave it out.

Comment: Uhm... today I have a problem using your solution: if my final timespan is

TotalHours = -4.333333333333333
TotalHours = -20

Using yuor sintax, final result is "-05:20"

Instead I would have expected "-04:20"

Comment: Yes I didn't consider negative values. `Floor` goes in the wrong direction for negatives as you want to round towards zero, not strictly downwards. `Math.Truncate` is what you want to handle both, editing answer to match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`TotalHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the total (fractional) number of hours.

So instead, maybe:

```
label.text = string.Format("{0:N2}:{1:N2}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours) + ":" + ts.Minutes);
```